# Split string into HTML entities

Tags: php, json, hyperlink, split

I'm trying to use PHP to create a JSON representation of a paragraph of text, keeping information about links/formatting etc.

Essentially, I want to convert this string:

```
"Hello <a href='www.google.com'>World!</a>.  How are <b>you</b> today?"
```

Into these 7 JSON objects:

```
"1": {
    "_id": "1",
    "_type": "TEXT",
    "value": "Hello "
},
"2": {
    "_id": "2",
    "_type": "TEXT",
    "value": "World!",
    "_attributes": {
        "3": {
            "_id": "3",
            "_type": "LINK",
            "src": "www.google.com"
        }
    }
},
"4": {
    "_id": "4",
    "_type": "TEXT",
    "value": " How are "
},
"5": {
    "_id": "5",
    "_type": "TEXT",
    "value": "you",
    "_attributes": {
        "6": {
            "_id": "6",
            "_type": "FORMATTING",
            "bold": true,
        }
    }
},
"7": {
    "_id": "7",
    "_type": "TEXT",
    "value": " today?"
}
```

I've hunted the internet/google and found plenty about splitting HTML, but can't seem to describe what I want.  I need to separate the plain text from the link/formatting and create a single entity for each.

The "FORMATTING" attribute just adds "bold"/"underline"/"subscript" etc fields as appropriate.

Nested tags will simply create multiple attributes for their text entity.

I don't yet know how I'd handle a 2-word hyperlink that has one word bolded... perhaps it'll have to have 2 hyperlink attributes.

Any help MUCH appreciated!!

Comment: A `DOMDocument` is what you need. If you can live with slightly different names, you barely have to do any work, too.

Comment: DOMDocument .getElementsByTagName(p) returns the entire string as plaintext.  I need to be able to get all the text BEFORE the link, the link, all the text after the link until the next formatting change, etc etc.

If I try and split on the link text, then a paragraph with a link on a word that occurs without a link later on will cause the link to be applied to both words.

Comment: Perhaps I just dont understand DOMDocument properly.  I've spent a lot of time at php.net looking into it (before posting here) but couldn't work out how I'd do it.  Are you able to help me with a little example?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return a string, it's just converted to a string, probably because you're `echo`ing it. I'll come up with an example in a bit, but in the meantime, try browsing the php.net documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm looking through tutorials now, but I can't see how I can get "Hello " from "<p>Hello World!</p>", even if "World!" is a hyperlink.  The DOMDocument holds the entire <p> as one element, and the <a> as another (I think).  Is there some kind of XOR I could use to take the link out of the <p>? lol

Comment: It's a tree, not a list. Traverse a node's children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DOMDocument is what you need. If you can live with slightly different names, you barely have to do any work, too.